# Output both to console and file

Tags: python

BUT:

1. No external shell commands, e.g. `| tee`.
2. No new functions and a change of syntax, e.g., keep using `print()` as is.

Comment: Please provide some [Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You could write a class that implements *write()* then pass a reference to that class to the *file* argument in *print()*

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom class that that has a `.write(string)` method and can be passed as the `file=` parameter to [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) and internally handles calls to `.write()` by writing the same content to multiple other file objects.

Example implementation:

```py
import sys
from typing import TextIO

class MultiTextIO:
    def __init__(self, *fds: TextIO):
        self.fds = fds

    def write(self, b, /):
        for fd in self.fds:
            fd.write(b)

fp = open(sys.argv[1] if 1 < len(sys.argv) else "output.txt", "w")
multi_output_io = MultiTextIO(sys.stdout, fp)

print("Hello, World!", file=multi_output_io)
```

Example usage:

```bash
$ python output2.py
Hello, World!
$ cat output.txt
Hello, World!
```

Comment: You don't need to subclass io.TextIOBase because any class that implements *write()* is acceptable to print's *file* argument

Comment: Requires change of syntax, passing a file arg.